# How do I create a Ruby class that initializes and closes when passed a block?

Tags: ruby, class, block

Ruby has the File class that can be initialized using the normal `new()` method, or using `open()` and passing a block.  How would I write a class that behaved like this?

```
File.open("myfile.txt","r") do |f|
...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple example of passing a block to `new/open` method

```
class Foo
  def initialize(args, &block)
    if block_given?
       p block.call(args) # or do_something
    else
      #do_something else
    end

  end

  def self.open(args, &block)
    if block_given?
      a = new(args, &block)  # or do_something
    else
      #do_something else
    end
  ensure
    a.close
  end

  def close
     puts "closing"
  end


end

Foo.new("foo") { |x|  "This is #{x} in new" } 
# >> "This is foo in new"
Foo.open("foo") { |x|  "This is #{x} in open" } 
# >> "This is foo in open"
# >> closing
```

Comment: If no block is passed (`Foo.new("foo")` or `Foo.open("foo")`), `block => nil` (`block` being a `proc`). This means that you can replace `if block_given?` with just `if block`. `block_given?` is normally used with `yield` (i.e., is true if `yield` has anything to do), but here it appears to indicate if the last parameter is a proc. I was not aware of that behavour.

Comment: +1 for the elaboration of the different flavors, but -1 for the bug: without putting the close method in an `ensure`, it fails to clean up when the block raises an exception.

Comment: @PaulCantrell it is almost a pseudocode as a starting point to the OP's question, however I have added the ensure as you requested

Comment: The `ensure` is a crucial piece of this pattern, even in pseudocode. Without that, why are you even bothering with a block?

Note that the ensure block here doesn't quite work, because `a` doesn’t get assigned to until after `new` returns successfully. If the call to `new` raises an error, `a` will still be nil, so `a.close` (1) won’t free any allocated resources, and (2) will blow up trying to invoke a method on `nil`. (#1 might not be an issue, because GC will probably free stuff anyway — depending on how the classes in question are actually implemented.)

Answer (score 4):

The general outline of File.open is something like this:

```
def open(foo, bar)
  f = do_opening_stuff(foo, bar)
  begin
    yield f
  ensure
    do_closing_stuff(f)
  end
end
```

It is `yield` that invokes the block passed by the caller. Putting `do_closing_stuff` within an `ensure` guarantees that the file gets closed even if the block raises an exception.

More nitty-gritty on the various ways of calling blocks here: http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby

Comment: +1 for how close this is to the actual C implementation of `rb_io_s_open`.

Comment: Looks good, Paul.  You may want to elaborate a little to more closely mimic the different ways [File#open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-open) can be invoked, mainly the case where no block is passed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class method which creates an instance, `yield`s it, and then then performs cleanup after the `yield`.

```
class MyResource
  def self.open(thing, otherthing)
    r = self.new(thing, otherthing)
    yield r
    r.close
  end

  def initialize(thing, otherthing)
    @thing = thing
    @otherthing = otherthing
  end

  def do_stuff
    puts "Doing stuff with #{@thing} and #{@otherthing}"
  end

  def close
  end
end
```

Now, you can either use it with a constructor:

```
r = MyResource.new(1, 2)
r.do_stuff
r.close
```

or using a block, which automatically `close`s the object:

```
MyResource.open(1, 2) do |r|
  r.do_stuff
end
```